# Objective-C avoid UINib caching

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, didreceivememorywarning, uinib

I have an issue. In my app I use xib files with lots of images and I have noticed that UIViewController or UINib class caches nib file`s content in the memory. I do not need such kind of behavior. I need resources to be released after dealloc of ViewController. I can actually add some code to cause memory warning  but I am not sure that it will not lead to reject. If anyone has any idea please give an advice.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center postNotificationName:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
}
```